# ssl handshake exception in android gcm server

Tags: java, android, ssl, google-cloud-messaging

Hi friends I am new to android. I am trying to create gcm server. my code is

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","/usr/bin/keystore.jks");
String id = "cliend id";
String msg = "Test";
Sender sender = new Sender(Api key);
Message message = new Message.Builder()
        .addData("message", "this is the message")
        .addData("other-parameter", "some value")
        .build();
Result result;
result = sender.sendNoRetry(message, id);
```

I create keystore but still i have error like: `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.`

I am not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the certificate for App2 to the keystore file of the used JVM located at %JAVA_HOME%\lib\security\cacerts.

First you can check if your certificate is already in the keystore by running the following command: keytool -list -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" (you don't need to provide a password)

If your certificate is missing you can get it by downloading it with your browser and add it to the keystore with the following command:

keytool -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias  -file    -keystore  -storepass

Afer import you can run the first command again to check if your certificate was added.

Sun/Oracle information can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html).

Hope this helped! Have Fun!